# Nginx url arg parsing with dashes

Tags: nginx

I recently upgraded from nginx version 1.8 to 1.12, and I noticed that the map module has changed. The following works in 1.8, but no longer works in 1.12.

```
map $is_args $foo {
    default $arg_foo-bar
}
```

Instead, I have to remove the dash to get it to work properly.

```
map $is_args $foo {
    default $arg_foo_bar
}
```

I can't find anything in the change logs to explain this.

Edit: I tested the foo-bar variable in 1.10, and it works.

Comment: I'm trying to access a `data-foo` querystring parameter and can't get it to work with version `openresty/1.11.2.4` and `$arg_data_foo`. Was that you were trying?